# How to trigger Modern List View update after list item added via JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

So it seems that the answer to Sharepoint Forms is DOM injection to override the New and Edit buttons.  This can be accomplished pretty easily; however, upon saving any adds/updates to a list, the modern list view takes some time to update.

Is anyone aware of a method to trigger the list view to update?

Answer (score 0):

For this, one thing you can try - after adding the list items using JSOM - refresh the list automatically, you can use the below code:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">

function refreshPage() {

    window.location = window.Location;

}

setTimeout(refreshPage, 300000);

</script>
```

We can think of refreshing the list items once the item is added into the list using Microsoft Flow - but it is not yet implemented from Microsoft, the user has raised their voice for this, refer to the below threads for the same:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Flow-Ideas/idb-p/FlowIdeas
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Refresh-SharePoint-list-through-MS-Flow/m-p/122191#M3254